# AVAudioPlayer produces lag in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

yes I'm not the first one with this question but everything I found is like 4 Years old and I don't find the solution for this problem. Probably I just don't understand the solutions.

The Problem:

Every time I start the APP on a Device and call my "sound" file it lags for a short moment. I tried to set the sound into the background but it still lags. Also I set the Capabilitis option for background modes (Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture) in the project setup of the App.

For whatever reason calling the "sound" in the "background" works in the simulator from Xcode without any lags.

I`m using this code to call a m4a-format sound file:

```
var SoundCollect: AVAudioPlayer?

func SoundCollectStaff() {

do {

        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "collect", ofType: "m4a") {

            SoundCollect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))

            SoundCollect?.prepareToPlay()
            SoundCollect?.play()

        } else {

         print("no file found")
        }

} catch let error {
    print("error failed with: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

and this code to set the sound into the background

```
func SetSoundinBackground() {

    do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("Session is Active")

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

by calling the SetSoundinBackground() function I get on the Device the following `Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"`

Thanks for any help and advices!!

Comment: Hi man. What do you mean by sending the sound into the background via the method SetSoundinBackground()?

Comment: The method enables the app to use sound while the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

well the solution seems easy. I Added this to my SoundCollectStaff() function:

`DispatchQueue.global().async {
    SoundCollect.play()
}`